# Angular 8 ngFor table td unable to sort or search in datatables

Tags: angular, datatables, angular8

I am using Datatables for showing data in table. If I use plain TR and TD it works well. If I add the same in FOR loop it  doesn't work. Below is my code

```
<tr *ngFor="let info of lspOverAllInfoArray" role="row">
                          <td>{{ info[1] }}</td>
                          <td>{{ info[2] }}</td>
                          <td>{{ info[3] }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2</td>
                          <td>Someone</td>
                          <td>Youknow</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>3</td>
                          <td>Iamout</td>
                          <td>Ofinspiration</td>
                        </tr>
```

If i try to sort or search only last 2 records ( static ones) will appear after. all dynamically added data disappears.

Comment: Please share code related with your search method.

Comment: Any stackblitz working example would help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'customerEmailFilter'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) {
      return value;
    }
    return value.filter((val) => {
      let rVal = (val.id.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args)) || 
      (val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args)) ||
      (val.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args));
      return rVal;
    })

  }

}
```

Use this pipe in your HTML

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let customer of users | customerEmailFilter:email;let i = index">
    <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
    <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[Check this sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-search-filter-functionality-on-entire-table-5hqgyw)